# Improve visual delay/lag when VNC'ing from Linux into macOS?

Tags: linux, mac, vnc

On my Mac Mini  I have enabled Screen Sharing via System Preferences.
I can successfully connect a VNC client from my Arch Linux, but there is an annoying lag/delay.
There is a monitor connected and I can see that input (include mouse movements) arrives immediately, but the visual representation lags behind, e.g. when I type something in a Terminal, it takes up to 1 second to catch up.

Are there any settings on client or server that could improve the situation? Do I have to use an other VNC server on the Mac?

- macOS 11.4, 11.6
- I have tried TigerVNC, gvncviewer and also RealVNC
- the machines are connected via ethernet cable, `iperf` measures almost the full ~1Gbps

I hope this question fits here, the Mac/Unix-Linux SXs seemed to narrow.

---

UPDATE: I updated to 11.6, and the issue seemed gone, until I disconnected and connected again: same old delay.
Looks like it *can* but it *doesn't want to*...

Comment: There is time and delays in capturing video and encoding, and it is possible that the [built in VNC on the Mac is not using hardware capture and video encoding](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18404459) and is slow as a result. You may want to see if alternatives such as [nomachine](https://www.nomachine.com/download) or [Teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/download/mac-os/) offer better performance.

Comment: @Mokubai the HN thread seems to suggest that the ootb situation isn't great indeed. I gave nomachine a try and it seems to do a good job, thanks! Care to turn your comment into an answer I can accept?

Comment: Done, though I do wonder what is going on with the built in VNC. Seems to be a good few topic that say just use anything except the built in one, even just installing a "normal" VNC client is better: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255880/vnc-connections-from-a-mac-is-very-slow perhaps there is something in it that prefers Mac-to-Mac connections and confuses "standard" VNC implementations?

Comment: @Mokubai FWIW I have tried Gnome's vinagre, which wouldn't connect at all (my password was too long?!), and another client complained that this "Apple Remote Desktop" connection is unencrypted...

Comment: Yeah, that suggests to me that while it might be mostly VNC based there is some apple proprietary fluff bolted in that leaves more standard clients rather unhappy with it.  I'd be curious if it works better from Mac to Mac.

Comment: @Mokubai indeed, Mac to Mac has better performance. I have also tried switching from *Screen Sharing* to *Remote Management*, but short of a true Apple Remote Desktop (≠RDP) client, this just defaults back to VNC, as far as I can tell. Tried a bunch of clients (Remmina, RealVNC), color depths & compression (always stays Zlib) -- no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some suggestions on the internet that getting the built in version of VNC in MacOS to use GPU acceleration, which could improve performance, can be somewhat hit-or-miss. One [HackerNews article](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18404459) states

> I’ve seen lots of folks make reference to getting GPU-accelerated VNC that dramatically improves performance if the Mini is hooked up to a monitor, but in my experience it doesn’t work. The only acceptable remote desktop solution I’ve ever found for the Mac is NoMachine.

It may be worth trying alternatives such as [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com/download) or [Teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/download/mac-os/) which might offer better performance.

Comment: NoMachine worked well. But too bad we can't just use the built-in server (which seems just to be slow). Re: monitor - I have one connected and it made zero difference.

Comment: Update for passers-by: after using NoMachine a bunch it seems clunky and buggy. Haven't put the resources in yet to find out why, might be M1, YMMV...

Answer (score 0):

visually the vncsession seems to lag some times and response slow, other symptoms as font is garbled up
I have seen issues with VNC viewers specially for MAC users

and this solution work for me

Go to
VNCViewer → properties → expert
Filter for udp and set the variable "EnableUdpRfb" to false ( by default it is true )
Set the variable "ColorLevel" to pal8 (by default it is rgb222 which is 64 colors making some stuff, gedit in particular difficult to view)

Comment: didn't work for me, sorry. the other symptoms seem unrelated.

Comment: Just re-read this answer, and it seems to suggest that you are using a VNC viewer on Mac to VNC into a Linux VNC server (running gedit)? I was asking about the opposite situation.

Comment: I am using Real VNC to connect to a Mac, from a Mac.. Changing these settings does improve the experience, which was woeful with the default VNC Viewer settings. Still no where near the smoothness of Screen Sharing.. but much better than before.